# UDF Runs slowly compared to built in functions

Tags: excel, vba, performance, optimization, user-defined-functions

I heard of the new XLOOKUP function in certain test versions of Excel.

Since I do not have this I wanted to write my own, very basic, implementation of the XLOOKUP.

The code does what I want it to, but seems to run a little slow. I specifically notice when I autofill the function down next to a column of values it is much slower than the built in vlookup.

What optimizations can be made to fix the slowness?

I already added

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

and that made no difference (Yes I set the values back at the end).

I assume nothing further can be done; the VLOOKUP (and all built in functions) is probably compiled C++, and that is why it runs so fast.

I also switched my WHILE loop to a For Each and it seemed a little slower.

```vb
Public Function XLOOKUP(ByVal LookUpVal As Variant, ByVal SourceRange As Range, ByVal ResultRange As Range) As Variant

    Application.Volatile

    Dim SrcRange As Variant
    Dim RsltRange As Variant
    Dim IterCount As Long
    Dim ResultVal As Variant

    SrcRange = SourceRange.Value
    RsltRange = ResultRange.Value

    IterCount = 1
    If UBound(SrcRange, 1) > 1 Then
        While (Not LookUpVal = SrcRange(IterCount, 1))
            IterCount = IterCount + 1
        Wend
        If IterCount > UBound(SrcRange, 1) Then
            ResultVal = 0
        Else
            ResultVal = RsltRange(IterCount, 1)
        End If
    Else
        While (Not LookUpVal = SrcRange(1, IterCount))
            IterCount = IterCount + 1
        Wend
        If IterCount > UBound(SrcRange, 2) Then
            ResultVal = 0
        Else
            ResultVal = RsltRange(1, IterCount)
        End If
    End If

    SrcRange = Empty
    RsltRange = Empty
    XLOOKUP = ResultVal

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for all the looping and arrays:

```
Public Function myXLOOKUP(ByVal LookUpVal As Variant, ByVal SourceRange As Range, ByVal ResultRange As Range) As Variant
    myXLOOKUP = ResultRange(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(LookUpVal, SourceRange, 0))
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Scott.  This is a much more simple option.  It did run in about the same time so I am thinking it might be my hardware being slow.